# Issue with Server accepting multiple UDP datagrams on one port

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, udp, port

I'm making a UDP client/server program.  The client collects data and sends it to the server.

The client sends a datagram with a random port number to the server on a specific UDP port 6789.  The client and server then use the random port to share information.

The problem I have is that only one client can connect.  I feel that it is because port 6789 never gets reopened for the next client.

This is the code just for the server receiving the initial connection on port 6789.

```
public class MonitorServer extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

try{

    DatagramSocket connectSocket = new DatagramSocket(6789);     
    while( true )
    {
            String portString = "";
            int portInt = 0;
            byte [] buffer = new byte[100];

System.out.println("portTest 01 " +portInt);
            DatagramPacket portPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            connectSocket.receive(portPacket);
            portString = new String (portPacket.getData());
            connectSocket.disconnect();  
            connectSocket.close();

System.out.println("portTest 02 " +portString);
            portString = portString.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");
            portInt = Integer.parseInt(portString);

System.out.println("portTest 03 " +portString);                    
            ClientConnection c = new ClientConnection(portInt);
            new Thread(c).start();

System.out.println("portTest 04 " +portString); //<<-- never prints
   }
  }

  catch (Exception e) {}
 }

}
```

It seems like this section of code only runs once.  I added System.outs to troubleshoot and it looks like it stops at:

```
            ClientConnection c = new ClientConnection(portInt);
            new Thread(c).start();

System.out.println("portTest 04 ");  //<-- Never prints
```

I need it to keep running to accept connections.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the method MonitorServer.startServer never returns because it enters an infinite while loop. This means that `MonitorServer`'s constructor never returns which means that the while loop in main never reaches the close and never loops. You need to start `MonitorServer` in a new `Thread` or `Executor Service`

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, I took out the while loop but same results first client connects and sends data.  No other client can connect after the first one.

Comment: Yeah, but now you don't have any loops nor are the starting any threads to do your listening. I don't know what ClientConnection is or what is does but your main doesn't have a loop so now your server is only listening once and only creating one MonitorServer. Also this means that your application is probably exiting as soon as this happens.

Comment: You obviously have a lot of issues here that you need to resolve. I suggest doing some more research. I am signing out so good luck.

Comment: I made changes to call a new thread for ClientConnection, still only works for one client though. When ClientConnection is called it listens on the port it's assigned for the client and then prints the data the client sends it.  Which works, but for only one client.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  I'm calling a new Thread for ClientConnection not main().

Answer (score 0):

You should create the socket on 5678 once, outside the receiving loop. Not every time you receive.

NB there is no such thing as 'connectig' in UDP, apart from the limited stuff that DatagramSocket.connect() does, which is unknown to the peer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I moved the creation of the connectSocket outside the while loop.  The while loop never goes past "new Thread(c).start();

Comment: @Joshua It probably doesn't go beyond new ClientConnection(...), and that would be because you are doing some blocking operation in that constructor that should be in its run() method.